# C++ Help on refactoring a monster class

Tags: c++, refactoring, anti-patterns, oop

I have a C background and am a newb on C++. I have a basic design question. I have a class (I'll call it "chef" b/c the problem I have seems very analogous to this, both in terms of complexity and issues) that basically works like this

```
    class chef
    {
    public:
          void prep();
          void cook();
          void plate();

    private: 
          char name;
          char dish_responsible_for;
          int shift_working;
          etc...
    }
```

in pseudo code, this gets implemented along the lines of:

```
   int main{
    chef my_chef;
    kitchen_class kitchen;
    for (day=0; day < 365; day++)
         {
         kitchen.opens();
         ....

         my_chef.prep();
         my_chef.cook();
         my_chef.plate();

         ....

         kitchen.closes();
         }
   }
```

The chef class here seems to be a monster class, and has the potential of becoming one. chef also seems to violate the single responsibility principle, so instead we should have something like:

```
  class employee
  {
  protected: 
        char name;
        int shift_working;
  }

  class kitchen_worker : employee
  {
  protected: 
        dish_responsible_for;
  }

  class cook_food : kitchen_worker
  {
  public:
        void cook();
        etc...
  }
  class prep_food : kitchen_worker
  {
  public:
        void prep();
        etc...
  }
```

and

```
     class plater : kitchen_worker
     {
     public:
         void plate();
     }
```

etc...

I'm admittedly still struggling with how to implement it at run time so that, if for example plater (or "chef in his capacity as plater") decides to go home midway through dinner service, then the chef has to work a new shift.

This seems to be related to a broader question I have that if the same person invariably does the prepping, cooking and plating in this example, what is the real practical advantage of having this hierarchy of classes to model what a single chef does? I guess that runs into the "fear of adding classes" thing, but at the same time, right now or in the foreseeable future I don't think maintaining the chef class in its entirety is terribly cumbersome. I also think that it's in a very real sense easier for a naive reader of the code to see the three different methods in the chef object and move on.

I understand it might threaten to become unwieldy when/if we add methods like "cut_onions()", "cut_carrots()", etc..., perhaps each with their own data, but it seems those can be dealt with by having making the prep() function, say, more modular. Moreover, it seems that the SRP taken to its logical conclusion would create a class "onion_cutters" "carrot_cutters" etc... and I still have a hard time seeing the value of that, given that somehow the program has to make sure that the same employee cuts the onions and the carrots which helps with keeping the state variable the same across methods (e.g., if the employee cuts his finger cutting onions he is no longer eligible to cut carrots), whereas in the monster object chef class it seems that all that gets taken care of.

Of course, I understand that this then becomes less about having a meaningful "object oriented design", but it seems to me that if we have to have separate objects for each of the chef's tasks (which seems unnatural, given that the same person is doing all three function) then that seems to prioritize software design over the conceptual model. I feel an object oriented design is helpful here if we want to have, say, "meat_chef" "sous_chef" "three_star_chef" that are likely different people. Moreover, related to the runtime problem is that there is an overhead in complexity it seems, under the strict application of the single responsibility principle, that has to make sure the underlying data that make up the base class employee get changed and that this change is reflected in subsequent time steps.

I'm therefore rather tempted to leave it more or less as is. If somebody could clarify why this would be a bad idea (and if you have suggestions on how best to proceed) I'd be most obliged.

Comment: Sometimes mapping real world roles/responsibilities/tasks to objects in code just does not work. Maybe you need some generic function that takes a person and an action. That function gets the person to apply the action.

Comment: module on each class interface may give you more clues? like what a plater can do? what cook_food can do? do they need to inherite or it's just a skill(function call)?

Comment: Look at composition method. Or maybe you need a state pattern here?

Comment: many thanks for the suggestions everyone, they give me good places to start!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid abusing class heirarchies now and in future, you should really only use it when an **is** relationship is present. As yourself, "is cook_food a kitchen_worker". It obviously doesn't make sense in real life, and doesn't in code either. "cook_food" is an action, so it might make sense to create an action class, and subclass that instead.

Having a new class just to add new methods like `cook()` and `prep()` isn't really an improvement on the original problem anyway - since all you've done is wrapped the method inside a class. What you really wanted was to make an abstraction to do any of these actions - so back to the action class.

```
class action {
    public:
        virtual void perform_action()=0;
}

class cook_food : public action {
    public:
        virtual void perform_action() {
            //do cooking;
        }
}
```

A chef can then be given a list of actions to perform in the order you specify. Say for example, a queue.

```
class chef {
    ...
        perform_actions(queue<action>& actions) {
            for (action &a : actions) {
                a.perform_action();
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

This is more commonly known as the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). It promotes the open/closed principle, by allowing you to add new actions without modifying your existing classes.

---

An alternative approach you could use is a [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method), where you specify a sequence of abstract steps, and use subclasses to implement the specific behaviour for each one.

```
class dish_maker {
    protected:
        virtual void prep() = 0;
        virtual void cook() = 0;
        virtual void plate() = 0;

    public:
        void make_dish() {
            prep();
            cook();
            plate();
        }
}

class onion_soup_dish_maker : public dish_maker {
    protected:
        virtual void prep() { ... }
        virtual void cook() { ... }
        virtual void plate() { ... }
}
```

Another closely related pattern which might be suitable for this is the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

These patterns can also reduce of the [Sequential Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling) anti-pattern, as it's all too easy to forget to call some methods, or call them in the right order, particularly if you're doing it multiple times. You could also consider putting your kitchen.opens() and closes() into a similar template method, than you don't need to worry about closes() being called.

---

On creating individual classes for onion_cutter and carrot_cutter, this isn't really the logical conclusion of the SRP, but in fact a violation of it - because you're making classes which are responsible for cutting, and holding some information about what they're cutting. Both cutting onions and carrots can be abstracted into a single cutting action - and you can specify which object to cut, and add a redirection to each individual class if you need specific code for each object.

One step would be to create an abstraction to say something is cuttable. The **is** relationship for subclassing is candidate, since a carrot *is* cuttable.

```
class cuttable {
    public:
        virtual void cut()=0;
}

class carrot : public cuttable {
    public:
      virtual void cut() {
          //specific code for cutting a carrot;
      }
}
```

The cutting action can take a cuttable object and perform any common cutting action that's applicable to all cuttables, and can also apply the specific cut behaviour of each object.

```
class cutting_action : public action {
    private:
        cuttable* object;
    public:
        cutting_action(cuttable* obj) : object(obj) { }
        virtual void perform_action() {
            //common cutting code
            object->cut(); //specific cutting code
        }
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks for that. I meant to follow it up with a question. So if we follow the strategy pattern approach, lets say each chef has many data members (e.g., tasting_spoon, salt_shaker, etc...) used in both the cook_food() and plate_dish() class. It seems then class chef needs cook_food() and cook_food() needs class chef. How does one avoid circular dependency between say cook_food() and class chef without having to give a ton of arguments to the cook_food() class? From a design perspective, if the classes are highly coupled, isn't there a demerit to separating them?

Comment: One way to avoid the circular dependency would be to create a chef interface, which the cook_food class can consume, and the actual chef class can implement. As long as the interface only specifies the details necessary for the cook_food to know of the chef, there's no problem. (or you could do it the other way round, and make a cooking interface for the chef to consume.) There's no single right way, but there's certainly merit to separating each task into it's own class.

Comment: Sorry, what does it mean for a class to be able to consume an interface? Does it mean doing something like, if we go with the interface on the chef class, for example, cook_food(chef->interface_for_cooking()), with interface_for_cooking() made up of calls like get_salt_shaker(), get_tasting_spoon() etc...? And to follow with this example, would it be a bad idea to have two separate interfaces for the cook_food() and plate_dish() classes?